# Автоматизация docker

Tags: docker, websocket, daemon

нужно автоматически запустить websocket server внутри docker контейнера. Уже пробовал через Dockerfile и docker-compose.yml, но докер ждет окончание выполнения скрипта демона из-за чего не стартует контейнер.

Comment: Для запуска чего-то в запускаемом контейнере используется инструкция CMD. Она у вас не работает или в чём суть проблемы-то? Как вы добились того, что докер чего-то там ждёт?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я вспомнил про основную концепцию докера: Один контейнер - один процесс, и запустил websocket server в отдельном контейнере и всё заработало.

Comment: Скорее один контейнер - один сервис.